# Flutter - broadcast events to a widget?

Tags: flutter

With Flutter, is it possible to post an event to a queue that other widgets can pick up with a listener designed to capture the event?

For example, I have a logout method that is actioned in my app drawer menu widget. Once the user selects the logout action I want to broadcast a logout event to other widgets and providers.

Comment: use StreamController and StreamBuilder. You can use different state management libraries like